# How do I format this JSON date inside datatables.net table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the jQuery plugin datatables.net to display data tables. For the date database field, it reads:

```
DateOfEvent: "/Date(1453831200000-0500)/"
```

I need it to say Month/Day/Year in one section.

This is the code now.

```js
var dataTable=[];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $.ajax({ 
    url: urls[i],
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
 data = $(data).map(function(i, element) {
   element['DateOfEvent'] = new Date(parseInt(element['DateOfEvent'].match(/Date\((\d+)-(\d+)\)/)[1]));
   return element;
 });
```

And in the other to say  mm/dd/yyyy and time.

```js
'<tr>'+
 '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: #484848 ;">Date & Time</td>'+
   <td>'+d.DateOfEvent+'</td>'+
  '</tr>'+
```

Comment: why don't you send it as proper iso date format from server?

Comment: Are you saying the server can put it in the format that I need it to display? I work with IT so I don't know if they can do that.

Comment: @charlietfl Update: okay checked with my boss. The answer is no. I need to parse it somehow. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
$(data).map(function(i, element) {
     var re = /-?\d+/; // Regular expression for '\/Date(ticks)\/'
     var m = re.exec(item['DateOfEvent']);  
     var d = new Date(parseInt(m[0])); // Convert date ticks to Javascript Date
     element['DateOfEvent'] = d;
     return element;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work with the existing code for some reason. Thank you for your effort. U

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
new Date(+element['DateOfEvent'].replace(/\-\d+|[^\d]+/g, ''))
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. The return result was format /Date(1462334400000-0400). Thank you for your help and effort though.

Comment: @PandaNinja Is it a string `"/Date(1462334400000-0400)/"` or other data type?

Comment: Yes that is the string.